# How to view VHDL syntax errors in Atom?

Tags: vhdl, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I want to use Atom, for VHDL development. [language-vhdl](https://atom.io/packages/language-vhdl) plugin mention, that syntax highlighting just added. However, no syntax error showed.

How to view syntax errors in Atom?

Comment: Showing *syntax errors* is something completely different than showing *syntax highlighting*. It needs more analysis and for sure some adjustments concerning the chosen standard, for example. Since the linked plug-in is in its infancy, given the version number, I would *not* expect syntax errors shown. -- Anyway, you might like to search for the possibilities to create a user-defined error parser, like Eclipse can do. Since I don't use Atom, I have no idea whether it can do it, too. Such an error parser could at least mark diagnostic output in the build console.

Comment: I don't regularly use atom and don't depend on editors to highlight syntax or more importantly semantic errors. There is a Linux plugin for atom that supports syntax checking - [VHDL-Tool](https://www.vhdltool.com).

Comment: There may be some degree of anticipation for potential atom users of [ghdl-ls](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl-language-server) waiting for someone to play the bunny and implement an extension for atom. Editors with extensions for use as IDEs typically extend to using command line VHDL tools  return errors to point to both syntax and semantic errors. I recall doing this with joe (Joe's Own Editor, the author Joe Allen) a decade or so ago. atom is also missing other support such as VHDL code folding.

Comment: There is a [ide-vhdl package for Atom](https://atom.io/packages/ide-vhdl) which uses a Rust based vhdl-ls. I recall seeing Olof discuss it's limitations in general terms on [gitter](https://gitter.im/ghdl1/Lobby). (There are no VHDL implementations fully conforming to the -2008 or any other revision, even commercial tools are in perpetual beta).  The issue here is complexity. Target language are described in one domain, language servers are described in a different domain and their uses in editors in another. It's safe to say atom based VHDL syntax checking isn't ready for casual end users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found, that [linter-vhdl](https://atom.io/packages/linter-vhdl) fulfill my requirements.